# AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'colnames'

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, group-by

I have a list of column names as shown below:

```
colnames = ['split1', 'split2', 'split3', 'split4', 'split5', 'split6', 'split7']
```

I have used this in a line of code where I iterate over the list items as shown below:

```
for i in range(0,x+2):
    df[d[i+1]] = df.groupby(d[i]).colnames[i].transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
```

This is giving me the attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

But if I individually give the colname items to the code, it works fine:

```
df['dot2'] = df.groupby('dot1').split1.transform(lambda x : x.factorize()[0]+1)
```

Comment: What is `d` in `df.groupby(d[i])`?

Comment: d is another list of columns: d = ['dot1', 'dot2', 'dot3', 'dot4', 'dot5', 'dot6', 'dot7']

Answer (score 1):

In `df.groupby(d[i]).colnames[i]`, `colnames[i]` is a variable. You may need do

```py
df.groupby(d[i])[f'{colnames[i]}']
```